# How to align Google+ share button horizontally with the other (Facebook Like and Twitter buttons)

Tags: css, google-plus, vertical-alignment

The generated Google+ share button is given the following element style:

```
font-size: 1px;
vertical-align: baseline;
```

Placing the button with such a style in the same line with the other social buttons, will make the Google+ button display vertically displaced towards the bottom. (because the font of that element is `1px` high):

[image]

Hoe can I wrap the buttons to cancel the `vertical-align`-ment of the Google+ button. If in DevTools I change it to `top` the buttons are properly aligned. (Or if I remove the `font-size` property)

Or any other solution (except using `!important` and the dynamically generated ID of the generated `div`)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this css code :

```
iframe {
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: bottom !important;
}
```

Why iframe? because, they load using iframe to show the button in your page.
You can check example on [my blog page](http://www.mdesain.com/blog/web-design/profit-of-website-or-web-design)

Comment: Thx to fix, sory with my bad english

Comment: I also placed twitter into a div with `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to solve this problem using TABLE tag

```
<table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td> 
      [Facebook Share Button Code]
    </td>
    <td>
      [Google+ Share Button Code]
    </td>
    <td>
      [Twitter Tweet Link Code]
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```